# SDWebImage library not loading image from cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, sdwebimage

```
[cell.userProfileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userObject.profileImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profile"]];
```

After the image loads , if the app goes to background and then comes back to foreground, SDWebImage library dosen't load the image from cache.

Comment: Have you checked that you haven't written any code anywhere to remove cache data in your application?

Answer (score 0):

For doing it more efficiently, you should use AsynchronousImageView
https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView